# Returning reference from a function in Rust

Tags: rust

Following is a program that returns the reference to the largest value of any given vector.I used generics for this, but does not work.

```
fn largest<T : PartialOrd>(vec : &[T]) -> &T{

let mut biggest = vec[0];
 
for &item in vec{
    if item > biggest{
        biggest = item
    }
 }

 &biggest
}
```

I know I am returning a reference to a local variable, so It won't compile. The other solution is to use `copy` trait like,

```
fn largest<T : PartialOrd + Copy>(vec : &[T]) -> T{}
```

Is there any way so that I can return the reference and avoid using `Copy` trait?

Comment: I'm not particularly experienced with Rust but aren't lifetime parameters supposed to be used here?

Comment: Try `let mut biggest = &vec[0];`  You want `biggest` to be a reference instead of a copy of `vec[0]`.

Comment: @Bernard that brings the issue of comparing item with biggest.

Comment: [Lifetime annotations in function signatures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-function-signatures)

Comment: You shouldn't need a lifetime annotation - if there is only one reference parameter, Rust deduces that the returned reference must have the same lifetime as the reference parameter.  Lifetime deduction only looks at the function signature, not the body.

Comment: The problem here is that if you want to return a reference, `biggest` would have to hold a reference the entire time.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=52234e81ca57b34dce5f1d9d0a62a5cb Does this help you?

Comment: Not directly related to question but, `fn` like this should return `Option<&T>`

Comment: @ĐorđeZeljić I think that depends on the use case.  Unless you're writing panic-free code altogether, it might be reasonable to say that it's a precondition of this function that `vec` must be non-empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
fn largest<T : PartialOrd>(vec : &[T]) -> &T{

let mut biggest = &vec[0];
 
for item in vec{
    if item > biggest{
        biggest = item
    }
 }

 biggest
}
```

`biggest` is a reference of type `mut &T`, so the reference can be rebinded later at the line `biggest = item`.

By doing it this way, at no point in the code will you be making copies of `T`, and so will be returning a reference to one of the elements of the slice.